# How to restore or reapply users choices to ng-select dropdowns after the data is returned back to the view after a save?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an angular app that shows all records, this page can be filtered using 3 select menus.

When a record is edited I would like to restore the filters to the users choices prior to editing the record, at the moment it clears the filters/select boxes and returns all the records again, which could be a little frustrating for a user.

I am already collecting their choices in $scope but how would reapply those choices programmatically, is there an angular trick or perhaps jquery?
What is the best way to achieve this in angularJS?

Comment: Thankyou @Mike i didn't know that :)

Comment: Please add some code sample or a plnkr to demonstrate your problem. Abstract questions means abstract answers